# How to fill url blank spaces in codigniter with something else?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create a url for search results with input values included in url. Everything is working fine except "blank spaces".

I am getting this at the moment:

> localhost/admin/search-results/san diego-01/25/2016-01/27/2016-guest House-7

PS, 'San Diego' & 'Guest House'. I can manually change the value of drop downs by adding '-' in value but I afraid doing so will not query DB. Same goes for location text input.

Controller:

```
public function custom_search() {
    $seg1 = $this->input->post('search[1]');
    $seg2 = $this->input->post('search[2]');
    $seg3 = $this->input->post('search[3]');
    $seg4 = $this->input->post('search[4]');
    $seg5 = $this->input->post('search[5]');

    $segment_array = $this->input->post('search');
    $segments = implode("-", $segment_array);
    redirect('search-results/'.$segments);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use `urlencode` function.

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

```
public function custom_search() {
    $seg1 = $this->input->post('search[1]');
    $seg2 = $this->input->post('search[2]');
    $seg3 = $this->input->post('search[3]');
    $seg4 = $this->input->post('search[4]');
    $seg5 = $this->input->post('search[5]');

    $segment_array = $this->input->post('search');
    $segments = implode("-", $segment_array);
    redirect('search-results/'.urlencode($segments));
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Looks like it filled the gap but "%2" appear there now

Comment: @CodeIgniter : Yes and on other page you can use `urldecode()` if you need to get the raw string. Do accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: are '%2' considered to be good for urls? I mean is that one have to live with if no solution for this (gap)? Just curious?

Comment: Yes there is no problem with this url

Comment: Actually, it's `%20`. More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner Yes it must be `%20` and not `%2`.